# Unable to generate server.csr for self-signed certificate

Tags: https, openssl, private-key, csr

I'm trying to generate a self-signed certificate for my website. I was able to generate the server.key file but when I try to execute the command for generating server.csr file to proceed further, I don't receive any error but the csr file isn't generated either. I don't find the file anywhere on my machine. Here's the command I'm using

I've tried saving the file to a known location. I've even tried giving full permission to the folder containing openssl application and even tried running in admin mode.

Here's the point from which I'm unable to move forward:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>openssl req -config "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\GnuWin32\share\openssl.cnf" -new -key server.key -sha256 -out 
server.csr
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a 
DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:IN
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Delhi
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Delhi
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:CT
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:IT
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:flyingtreat.com
Email Address []:hello@flyingtreat.com
```

gives no error. Following is the last thing it'll and all I see is the prompt again.

```
Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:killpir@cy

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>
```

I don't understand if the server.csr file is generated or not. Please help!

Comment: Please provide the config file or try without it.

Comment: If I don't use the config file, I receive an error saying "error: unable to load config file...."

Comment: @Oleg However, what you said provided me a solution. I downloaded the file from a third party source GnuWin32 which seems to be the issue. I uninstalled openssl and downloaded package files from Symantec website and same commands worked. I was able to generate .csr file.. Thanks!